# storing value in temporary database in user's device in android

Tags: android

I want to create a app where the user will be asked to enter his personal details in his first use then i want all those details to be set in the edit text when ever he reopens the app. How to do this ?
Can we store that in a temporary database in user's device?.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: You can simply use Shared Preferences for small data like user details.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this using SQLite Database.

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

//We need to pass database information along to superclass
public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

//Add a new row to the database
public void addProduct(Product product){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

//Delete a product from the database
public void deleteProduct(String productName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + productName + "\";");
}

public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";

    //Cursor points to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    //Position after the last row means the end of the results
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) {
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

Here i have created a class MyDBHandler which lets me delete and add the data using the functions addProduct and deleteProduct.

Then in my Mainactivity i can call the instance of MyDBHandler and then call its respective methods also to add or delete the data and it is going to appear in the editText or Textview even after you quit the app.

databaseToString method is being used to fetch the data from the database.

Comment: I would prefer Realm over SQLite. But the main thing is, I would never use a Database for storing minor user details. SharedPreferences are recommended for such tasks

Comment: As said SharedPreferences is what i need, thank you all for your support

Comment: `SharedPreferences` are best for small things. Database solution is very bad idea in this situation.